# Remove files listed in a CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv

I am currently trying to run a PowerShell script to delete a bunch of files listed in a CSV.  I am having no problem deleting files in the root directory of the drive. The script is just having issues when the file is within folders. I have tried adding `" "` to the file path and name and it still doesn't work. I am using PowerShell version 2.0.

CSV sample (`remove.csv`):

```
D:\Data\HomeDrives\stusers\user\My Documents\SC\setup.exe
```

PowerShell script:

```
$files = Get-Content "D:remove.csv"

foreach ($file in $files) {
    Remove-Item -Path $file -Force
}

Write-Host -foregroundcolor yellow "Delete action complete"
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Remove-Item : Cannot find path ' D:\Data\HomeDrives\stusers\user\My Documents\SC\setup.exe'
does not exist.
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId: PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand.
```

I have checked and the file does exist.

Comment: What do you mean by it "having issues"? What exactly happens? Do you get an error message?

Comment: The error is Remove-Item  : Cannot find path '
D:\Data\HomeDrives\stusers\user\My Documents\SC\setup.exe' does not exist.  Followed by + FullyQualifiedErrorId: PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand.  I have checked and the file does exist

Comment: You have a space before the "D:" in your file. You could either remove that space or do `Remove-Item -Path $file.Trim() -force` in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path you read from the input file has a leading space. Either fix the input data, or [`Trim()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the string before removing the file (as mentioned in the comments to your question):

```
foreach ($file in $files) {
    Remove-Item -Path $file.Trim() -Force
}
```

You could also streamline your code by using a `ForEach-Object` loop instead of a `foreach` loop:

```
Get-Content 'D:\remove.csv' | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() } | Remove-Item -Force
```